# Is there a safe check I can do before calling DateTime.AddMonths(int months)?

Tags: c#, datetime

If I call AddMonths on a DateTime object using an int that is too large, I get an ArgumentException thrown in my face with a polite message that says,

"The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. 
Parameter name: months"

What check should I do on the months argument before calling this method?

Comment: How large is your int that's too large?

Comment: In this specific instance, 98 550.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx):

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> The resulting DateTime is less than [MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) or greater than [MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue.aspx).
>
> -or-
>
> months is less than -120,000 or greater than 120,000.

Based on your comment I'd say that the resultant months value is greater than 120,000.

You could get total months in the current date time and check that that plus your value isn't out of range, or catch the exception as others have suggested.

Comment: The first point makes is pretty hard to detect. You'll have to basically calculate the resulting value yourself, in which case, why would you bother calling `AddMonth`?

Comment: @Mehrdad - very true, so catching the exception might be the better way to go

Comment: Using (DateTime.MaxValue.Months + DateTime.MaxValue.Years * 12) to compare with the argument I'm using in AddMonths.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `AddMonths` method in a `try` block if you're anticipating such a problem.

Comment: Yes .. it's too tedious to try and check for conditions the other way .. and if you miss something there will still be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that ends up here, and like me, didn't like the accepted answer because, as the comments say, you're kind of doing half the work that the DateTime methods are meant to do, and also want to avoid the whole try-catch thing...

Instead, you can take the Min/Max value you're expecting to hit and work backwards from there:

```
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.MaxValue.AddMonths(-2) < myDate) {
    // it'll overflow
} else {
    // I can safely add two months to myDate
}
```

As I one-liner, in my circumstance, I ended up with:

```
toDate = DateTime.MaxValue.AddSeconds(-1) < fromDate ? DateTime.MaxValue : fromDate.AddSeconds(1);
```